# R command for substitute in increments

Tags: r

I would like to replace below:

```
[1] "annotated_SRR7059136_CD39-.txt" "annotated_SRR7059137_CD39+.txt"
[3] "annotated_SRR7059138_CD39-.txt" "annotated_SRR7059139_CD39+.txt"
[5] "annotated_SRR7059140_CD39-.txt" "annotated_SRR7059141_CD39+.txt"
[7] "annotated_SRR7059142_CD39-.txt" "annotated_SRR7059143_CD39+.txt"
```

into

```
[1] "1_CD39-.txt" "1_CD39+.txt"
[3] "2_CD39-.txt" "2_CD39+.txt"
[5] "3_CD39-.txt" "3_CD39+.txt"
[7] "4_CD39-.txt" "4_CD39+.txt"
```

So far, I've tried running this

```
x<- sub("annotated_SRR70591.*_","\\1",sampleFiles)
```

But I am getting

```
[1] "CD39-.txt" "CD39+.txt" "CD39-.txt" "CD39+.txt" "CD39-.txt" "CD39+.txt"
[7] "CD39-.txt" "CD39+.txt"
```

instead of what I wanted. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: how is prefix 1, 2, 3, 4 decided? or do you want first 2 entries to be 1, next  2 to be 2 and so on?

Comment: Thats right, just chronological order by the list.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rep` and `seq` to generate the numbers and `paste` them together.

```
paste0(rep(seq(length(sampleFiles)/2), each = 2), "_", 
           sub("annotated_SRR70591.*_","\\1",sampleFiles))

#[1] "1_CD39-.txt" "1_CD39+.txt" "2_CD39-.txt" "2_CD39+.txt" "3_CD39-.txt" 
#[6] "3_CD39+.txt" "4_CD39-.txt" "4_CD39+.txt"
```

---

For better understanding breaking down the steps,

```
rep(seq(length(sampleFiles)/2), each = 2) #gives
#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
```

and

```
sub("annotated_SRR70591.*_","\\1",sampleFiles) #gives
[1] "CD39-.txt" "CD39+.txt" "CD39-.txt" "CD39+.txt" "CD39-.txt" "CD39+.txt"
[7] "CD39-.txt" "CD39+.txt"
```